# Using CSS, how do I move a DIV to the left of the centre position?

Tags: html, css

A fairly standard way to horizontally centre a `DIV` is to set the left and right margins to `auto`.

However, I have a `DIV` that I want to be mostly horizontally centred, but I want to nudge it a little toward the left.

I tried setting the margins like so:

```
margin: 100px 60% 24px 40%;
```

... and also like this:

```
margin: 100px 40% 24px 60%;
```

... but *both* resulted in the DIV being positioned further to the right.

I tried adding padding to the `DIV`, but that also only moves it to the right.

In short, it seems no matter what I do, the `DIV` moves to the right, not to the left as desired.

How do I nudge a `DIV` a little to the left of centre?

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle please?

Comment: Set margin to auto and then margin-right separately

Comment: @EricLeschinski, please do not correct my UK/Canadian *centre* to the US spelling of *center*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out I was able to do what I needed to do with floating the DIVs.

```
.left,
.right {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    clear: both;
}

.left {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

A different way of handling this is making a parent wrapper div. Where you set that to auto so that parent is centered, but the child div is then starts at the center but moves to the right. See fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4H26W/1/

html

```
<div id="red">
    <div id="blue">Some text</div>
</div>
```

css

```
#red {
    width: 1px; /* you could actually just change it to 0px */
    margin: 100px auto;
    background: red;
}
#blue {
    width: 200px;
    background: blue;
}
```

Then if you wanted to further optimize the position of the child div, you could just add some left styles to it

```
position: relative; /* has to be position relative for left to work, or you could just do margin-left: -50px; too */
left: -50px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4H26W/2/

Answer (score 9):

Since you tagged `css3` for your question so you can use it :

```
margin: auto;
-webkit-transform: translateX(10px); /* 10px to left */
-moz-transform: translateX(10px); /* 10px to left */
-ms-transform: translateX(10px); /* 10px to left */
 transform: translateX(10px); /* 10px to left */
```

Answer (score 5):

there is an option with text-align, display and negative margin .

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Dzbat)**

---

HTML test base :

```
<div class="left">center on my left</div>
<hr/>
<div class="right">center on my right</div>
<hr/>
<div >center me</div>
```

---

CSS base:

```
body {
  text-align:center;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,gray 50%,white 50%)
}
div {
  width:20%;/* whatever */
  display:inline-block;
  border:solid;
}
.left {
  margin-left:-20%;/* whatever */
}

.right {
  margin-right:-20%;/* whatever */
}
```

[image: render]

Comment: @Gagan thanks, i have another example here :) http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/wqbjl it plays with negative margin so it pulls others as well

Answer (score 2):

If you set the `margin-right` or `margin-left` as a separate rule after setting the `margin` rule, you'll still get frustrated, but not as much:

```
<div id="first"></div>
<div id="second"></div>

div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 2em auto;
}

#second {
    margin-right: 42%;
}
```

See example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q7EHX/

Answer (score 1):

position relative.

```
<div style="margin:100px auto 24px;
    position:relative;left:-30px;
    border:1px solid red;width:200px
">should be a little off-center</div>
```